# Tkinter virtual LED

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, raspberry-pi3, indicator

I am currently using Tkinter to develop a GUI that can interface with Raspberry Pi board.I want a button connected to raspberry pi and get the output indication on Tkinter GUI such as Green indicates ON and Red indicates OFF.

Here is a code that I tried:-

```
from tkinter import *
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
buttonPin=11

GPIO.setup(buttonPin, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_DOWN)

win = Tk()

def ledON():
    while True:
        if GPIO.input(11) == 1:
            ledButton["bg"] = "green"
        else:
            ledButton["bg"] = "red"

#I tried to use button widget in DISABLED state as a Indicator
ledButton = Button(win, text = "   ", command = ledON,state=DISABLED, height = 2, width =8,bg="red")
ledButton.pack()

mainloop()
```

Please help me Out.

Comment: Please ask a specific question with a specific problem to solve. What is your error? What is not working as intended?

Comment: What kind of help do yo need? Your question doesn't include a question.

Comment: don't use `while True` loop because it blocks `mainloop` and it freeze program. Use `root.after(milliseconds, function)` to run function again without blocking `mainloop`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't use `while True` because it runs all time and it blocks `mainloop` which gets key/mouse events from system, sends events to widgets, (re)draws widgets, etc. If you block `mainloop` then it can't work and window freezes.

You can use `win.after(millisecond, function_name)` to repeate function without blocking `mainloop`

```
import tkinter as tk # PEP8: `import *` is not preferred
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO

# --- function ---

def my_function():
    
    if GPIO.input(11) == 1:
        led["bg"] = "green"
    else:
        led["bg"] = "red"
        
    # repeate function after 100ms (0.1s)
    win.after(100, my_function)
    
# -- main ---

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
buttonPin=11

GPIO.setup(buttonPin, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_DOWN)

win = tk.Tk()

led = tk.Label(win, text="   ", bg="red")
led.pack()

# run function first time
my_function()

mainloop()
```

---

**BTW:** If you really will have to use `while True` or run long running code then you can use `win.update()` to force `mainloop` to update widgets and redraw them.